# How to define customize frames in beamer with newenvironment

Tags: beamer, environments

I would like to change text distribution within each frame in my presentation beamer, I tried to use `\newenvironment` but every time I get an error:

> File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body

my MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myframe}{\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{\end{minipage}
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\begin{myframe}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Is there a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package `environ` is handy in such situations. Here is how it looks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][]{%
\begin{frame}{#1}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\BODY
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\begin{myframe}[Test]
\lipsum[2]
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have made the frame title optional in the new environment.

Comment: looks promising. It doesn't work with the `ignorenonframetext` option, though. Is there a way to make it work?