# Extend Beamer frame and inherit arguments (and overlays)

Tags: beamer, environments, overlays, optional-arguments

I intend to extend a beamer frame to save some overhead when making slides.

I've followed an [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605375/14470) after [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224679/14470) involving `NewEnviron` didn't  work for me. The [beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) has some details on re-defining an environment:
[image]

So I defined a "pictureframe" to have slide with two columns and a picture in the right column:

```
\newcommand\startcolumns{\begin{columns}}
\newcommand\stopcolumns{\end{columns}}
\newcommand\startleftcolumn{\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}}
\newcommand\startrightcolumn{\begin{column}{0.39\textwidth}}
\newcommand\stopcolumn{\end{column}}

\newenvironment{pictureframe}[2]{%
\newcommand\mypic{#2}
\begin{frame}[environment=pictureframe]{#1}
\startcolumns
\startleftcolumn
}{
\stopcolumn
\startrightcolumn
\centering\includegraphics{\mypic}
\stopcolumn
\stopcolumns
\end{frame}
}
```

Then, I can make a slide like this:

```
\begin{pictureframe}{Picture Frame}{example-image-a}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
\end{pictureframe}
```

[image]

Now, I want to be able to use 1) overlays and 2) labels, i.e.

```
\begin{pictureframe}<1>[label=picture,noframenumbering]{Picture Frame}{example-image-a}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
\end{pictureframe}
```

However, it doesn't compile:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `1' not found.
```

My question is: How do I properly "inherit" the frame environment, so that overlays and optional arguments are passed on, much like with a "real" frame?

Comment: If your want a new environment that is overlay specification-aware, you should define it using `\newenvironment<>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an environment overlay specification-aware. But you didn't write what these specifications should be used for (#4)...

The `\typeout{...}` shows the parameters.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\startleftcolumn{\column{0.55\textwidth}}
\newcommand\startrightcolumn{\column{0.39\textwidth}}

\newenvironment<>{pictureframe}[3][]{%
  \typeout{1:#1,2:#2,3:#3,4:#4}
  \begin{frame}#4[environment=pictureframe,#1]
    \newcommand\mypic{#3}
    \frametitle{#2}
    \columns
    \startleftcolumn
  }{
    \startrightcolumn
    \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\mypic}
    \endcolumns
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pictureframe}{Picture Frame}{example-image-a}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{pictureframe}

\begin{pictureframe}<1>[label=picture,noframenumbering]{Picture Frame}{example-image-a}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{pictureframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.
If you try to hide the frame with `<0>`, it still shows up: `\begin{pictureframe}<0>{Picture Frame}{example-image-a}`. The normal frame counterpart works as expected.

Comment: @FrederickNord I modified the code so that the overlays specifications are taken into account by the `pictureframe` environment as the `frame` environment does.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Is it possible to make works an `\againframe{picture}` before `\end{document}`?

Comment: @alexis I improved the code and so `\againframe` works.